# how to get this sql data with a join and non unique key relating two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables:

```
images
imageid   imageKeySTring
-------   --------------
98        AAA
97        BBB
96        CCC
95        CCC
94        BBB

objects
imageKeyString     id2
--------------     -----
AAA                2
BBB                3
AAA                4
CCC                5
CCC                6
BBB                7
```

All combinations of `id2` with `imageid` linked by matching `imageKeyString` how would I get this in an Oracle SQL query?

Example, for `CCC` I would get back:

```
5/95
5/96
6/95
6/96
```

returned (but I want all key returned values in the query)

Comment: seems like straigtforward inner join between two tables by ImageKeyString

Comment: Knowledge of keys (or other constraints) is not needed to query. What is necessary & sufficient to know is for each table--base & query result--its meaning--what a row in it says about the business situation in terms of column values. When constraints hold, further query expressions also return the same results that otherwise wouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a `join` would do what you ask.  It returns all matching rows from the joined table:

```
select  i.imageid
,       o.id2
from    images i
join    objects o
on      o.imageKeyString = s.ImageKeyString
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables together AND concatenate the results:

```
select i.imageKeyString,
       cast(o.id2 as varchar(10)||'/'||cast(i.imageid as varchar(10)) as newkey
from images i join
     objects o
     on i.imageKeyString = o.ImageKeyString
```

If some objects are missing:

```
select i.imageKeyString,
       coalesce(cast(o.id2 as varchar(10), '')||'/'||cast(i.imageid as varchar(10)) as newkey
from images i left outer join
     objects o
     on i.imageKeyString = o.ImageKeyString
```